# Why 'test=6 echo $test' command doesnot work in bash?

Tags: bash, scope

I came across this neat command to check the time of any timezone in bash

```
TZ=US/Hawaii date
```

Which does same as

```
export TZ=US/Hawaii
date
```

How does the first command work, while the following command doesn't work?

```
test=6 echo $test
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Variables are expanded *before* executing the commands in a line. So in the last example, `$test` is expanded before the assignment is done.

You can get the effect you want with:

```
test=6 bash -c 'echo $test'
```

This executes a new shell process. Since the argument is quoted, variables aren't expanded by the original shell, the subshell expands it in the environment where `$test` is set.

Answer (score 4):

In the first, the call to `date` uses the value of `TZ` that is put in its environment. In the second, the expansion of `$test` is performed by the shell *before* `echo` is actually run. The value of `test` in `echo`'s environment is irrelevant. A near-equivalent that works would be

```
(test=6; echo $test)
```